# Dynamic creation of forms & containers

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm very new to C#.

Below is a code that I'm trying to create forms and containers **within the code**; but I've problems with it.

1. I start with a new `Windows Forms Application` template.
2. I change the `Program.cs` file a little, so that I'd be able to create the `FormMain` dynamically.
3. When the lines `Container.Add(BtnClose)` and `BtnClose_Setup()` in `FormMain.cs` are commented, the code compile and run. However, there are still some weird results in the program.

(a) The form `FormMain` is supposed to show up at (20, 20) (upper left corner), as the `FormMain_Setup` says; but when I run the app, though width & height settings show up as expected (800, 600), the upper left corner changes every time (does not stick to 20, 20).

(b) The esc key works as expected and closes the form and application.

4. When the lines `Container.Add(BtnClose)` and `BtnClose_Setup()` in `FormMain.cs` are **not** commented, the code compile but VS sends me a message when it's run: "*An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll*"

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

`Program.cs` file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test {
    static class Program {
        public static FormMain FormMain = new FormMain();
        [STAThread]
        static void Main() {
            Application.Run(FormMain);
        }
    }
}
```

`FormMain.cs` file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test {
    public partial class FormMain : Form {
        Button BtnClose = new Button();
        public void BtnClose_Setup() {
            BtnClose.Text = "Ok";
            BtnClose.Top = 500;
            BtnClose.Left = 700;
        }
        public void FormMain_Setup() {
            Top = 20;
            Left = 20;
            Width = 800;
            Height = 600;
            KeyDown += FormMain_KeyDown;
            //Container.Add(BtnClose);
            //BtnClose_Setup();
        }
        void FormMain_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
            if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape) {
                Close();
            }
        }
        public FormMain() {
            InitializeComponent();
            FormMain_Setup();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a forms StartPosition is set to WindowsDefaultLocation. You need to set it to Manual; either in the designer or in the code.

To add a control to a form, you want to add it to the form's Controls collection, not the Container.

Also, if you want the form to continue to get KeyDown events after the button is added you need to set KeyPreview to true.

```
public void FormMain_Setup()
{
    StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
    KeyPreview = true;
    Top = 20;
    Left = 20;
    Width = 800;
    Height = 600;
    KeyDown += FormMain_KeyDown;
    Controls.Add(BtnClose);
    BtnClose_Setup();
}
```

Comment: Compared to overriding a default method, this seems a preferable solution.

Answer (score 2):

Call `Controls.Add(BtnClose);` instead of `Container.Add(BtnClose);`.

As for fixing the form position: set `StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;` property.

To properly close the form on Esc, override `ProcessCmdKey` method:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == Keys.Escape)
    {
        Close();
        return true;
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Comment: Tried & it works. Now the code compile & run; however this time the esc key does not close the form (& the app). And the upper left corner of the form still does not stick to (20, 20).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I'm getting somewhere.